# Unmarshal promoted fields into struct

Tags: go

I have two structs. One inherits from the other.

```
type Animal struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
    Color string `json:"color"`
}
```

When I go to `Unmarshal` to `Dog` by passing in:

```
{
  "name": "Loki",
  "color": "Brown"
}
```

I'm getting an `*encoding/json.InvalidUnmarshalError`. `2019/03/10 00:22:35 json: Unmarshal(nil *main.Dog)`

Why is that?

Here's the unmarshal code:

```
func main() {
    var dog *Dog

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
        "name": "Loki",
        "color": "Brown"
    }`), dog)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the variable `dog` is nil. Try to initialize it to point to an empty `Dog`. Or make it a `Dog` instead of a pointer to `Dog` and pass in the address to `Unmarshal`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to get the concepts straight -- there's no inheritance in Golang. Golang prefers composition over inheritance. What you're doing with `Animal` and `Dog` there is called [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) in Go.

Secondly, the correct way to use `json.Unmarshal` is to pass a pointer as the second argument. So, to fix your code:

```
func main() {
    var dog Dog

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
        "name": "Loki",
        "color": "Brown"
    }`), &dog)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

If you're familiar with C, think of `json.Unmarshal` as something similar to `scanf`. The caller pass an address to `scanf` so that `scanf` can "fill in the value" to the memory location represented by the pointer.